# Add modifier in child contract

Tags: solidity, openzeppelin, modifiers

I'm trying to implement my own ERC20 using openzeppelin.

```
contract MyERC20 is ERC20 { ... }
```

And I want to make function from ERC20 pausable using openzeppelin Pausable contract.
The question is - do I need to copy the whole function in MyERC20, for example:

```
function name() public view override whenPaused returns (string memory) {
    return _name;
}
```

Or there is the way to add modifier without copy of the function body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Solidity's inheritance: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.12/contracts.html#inheritance when you inherit from a contract, it will implements it's functions (as long as they are public or internal) and modifiers.

As you can see in OZ's ERC20.sol, the `name()` function is public and it looks the exact same as what you wanna do. In this case, you don't need to implement a new `name()` function.